# Group by a list in the where clause and then show the row whether it has a value or is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I was working on this query for awhile and I'm trying to figure out how to get this query to show all the initials in the `where clause` in the output table regardless as to whether that person has a p.Id or not. This is because I will be putting this information into a pre-formatted Excel table. Thanks in advance! EDITED:

```
SELECT 
    e.Initials, COUNT(p.Id) As "NT > 7"
FROM 
    Employees AS e
LEFT JOIN 
    Projects AS p
ON 
    e.Id = p.NTEmployeeId AND
    cast(p.NTDate as Datetime) < cast(dateadd(day, -7, (getdate())) as Datetime)
JOIN 
    Statuses AS s
ON 
    s.Id = p.StatusId AND
    s.Code in ('WIPR', 'RISK', 'PEND')
WHERE 
    e.Initials IN('af', 'cm' , 'jy','br','dfv','rxc','tm','axk','hd','sa','rw')
 GROUP BY (e.Initials);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional `left join` and to move the conditions on all but the first table into `on` clauses.  Remember, the `where` clause will turn the outer joins to inner joins, because `NULL` values don't (generally) match conditions.

```
SELECT e.Initials, COUNT(p.Id) As "NT > 7"
FROM Employees e LEFT JOIN 
     Projects p
     ON e.Id = p.NTEmployeeId AND
        cast(p.NTDate as Date) < cast(getdate() as date)  -- do date comparisons as dates, not strings
     LEFT JOIN  -- NEED LEFT JOIN HERE, or `ON` clause turns it into inner join
     Statuses s
     ON s.Id = p.StatusId AND
        s.Code in ('WIPR', 'RISK', 'PEND') -- `LIKE`/`OR` isn't wrong but `IN` is easier
WHERE e.Initials IN ('af', 'cm' , 'jy', 'br','dfv', 'rxc', 'tm', 'axk', 'hd', 'sa', 'rw')
 GROUP BY e.Initials;
```

I made a couple other changes:

- Use dates for comparing dates, not strings.  I think I have the logic right.
- Use `IN` instead of chains of `OR`s if you can.
- And for what you are doing, you might want to be counting the matching statuses rather than the matching people.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff for your input! I tried this out and while these changes do show all the initials listed the count of p.Ids increases way beyond the correct number if I use a left a join instead of an inner join. If I keep it an inner join I get the correct number of projects with NT days greater than 7 days but then I cannot see all the initials, just the ones that have p.id that meet the specified criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do to get the correct answer to display. Please see below:

```
SELECT
    e.Initials, COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Code in ('WIPR', 'RISK', 'PEND') 
and cast(p.NTDate as Datetime) < cast(dateadd(day, -7, (getdate())) as Datetime) THEN p.Id END) As "NT > 7"
FROM 
    Employees AS e
LEFT JOIN 
    Projects AS p
ON 
    e.Id = p.NTEmployeeId
JOIN 
    Statuses AS s
ON 
    s.Id = p.StatusId
WHERE 
     e.Initials IN('af', 'cm' , 'jy','br','dfv','rxc','tm','axk','hxd','rw')
GROUP BY (e.Initials);
```